# BibLaTeX' \citefield not expanded as expected

Tags: macros, biblatex, expansion

I have run into what looks like a macro expansion issue. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{expprob.bib}
@online{example,
  shorthand    = {foo-bar},
  url          = {http://example.com}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{expprob}

\newcommand{\demofield}[2]{foo-#1}
\newcommand{\demourl}[1]{\url{http://example.com/link/\demofield{#1}{shorthand}}}

\newcommand{\biburl}[1]{\url{http://example.com/link/\citefield{#1}{shorthand}}}

\begin{document}

\textbf{without biblatex}

expected: \url{http://example.com/link/foo-bar}

actual: \demourl{bar}

\textbf{with biblatex}

ze field: \citefield{example}{shorthand}

expected: \url{http://example.com/link/foo-bar}

actual: \biburl{example}

\end{document}
```

The commands `\demourl` and `\biburl` are quite similar, they just use different macros to determine a part of the URL. Processing this file (e. g. with `latexmk`) yields the following result:

[image: problem]

As you can see, the `\citefield` command works correctly and retrieves the contents of the `shorthand` attribute. The problem is that the macro is not expanded within `\url`, while the apparently similar `\demofield` is expanded correctly. I don't understand this - what is happening here, and how do I get the system to expand `\citefield` as well?

Comment: The difference seems to be that `\citefield` is a `\protected` command, so it doesn't get expanded in an `\edef`.

Comment: And, from what I see using `\tracingmacros=1`, `\citefield` has *better* be a `\protected` command. `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a bit about the pains involved in forcing *TeX to expand protected commands, I've changed my approach and used the BiBTeX facilities. The following code contains three command sets - one to print out the raw URL, one to format and link the URL using `\url` and one to create a `\href` hyperlink with some arbitrary text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}

% These are the parts used to print a raw URL without any formatting.
\DeclareFieldFormat{rawurl}{http://example.com/link/#1}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\rawurlcite}{}{\printfield[rawurl]{shorthand}}{}{}

% These are the parts used to print a hyperlinked URL.
\DeclareFieldFormat{linkurl}{\url{http://example.com/link/#1}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\linkurlcite}{}{\printfield[linkurl]{shorthand}}{}{}

% This provides a \hrefcite{key}{text} command
\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\@saveurlcite}{}{\savefield{shorthand}{\@savedshorthand}}{}{}
\newcommand{\hrefcite}[2]{%
\@saveurlcite{#1}%
\edef\@savedurl{http://example.com/link/\@savedshorthand}%
\href{\@savedurl}{#2}%
\let\@savedurl\empty%
\let\@savedshorthand\empty}

\begin{filecontents}{expprob.bib}
@online{example,
  shorthand    = {foo-bar},
  url          = {http://example.com}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{expprob}

\newcommand{\demofield}[2]{foo-#1}
\newcommand{\demourl}[1]{\url{http://example.com/link/\demofield{#1}{shorthand}}}

\newcommand{\biburl}[1]{\expandafter\url{\qlcite{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\textbf{without biblatex}

expected: \url{http://example.com/link/foo-bar}

actual: \demourl{bar}

\textbf{with biblatex}

ze field: \citefield{example}{shorthand}

rawurlcite: \rawurlcite{example}

linkurlcite: \linkurlcite{example}

a hyperlink: \hrefcite{example}{example text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I could have answered telling you to load the `usebib` package, then to say `\newbibfield{shorthand}` and `\bibinput{expprob}`, so `\newcommand{\biburl}[1]{\url{http://example.com/link/\usebibentry{#1}{shorthand}}}`. Of course yours is a better and more robust method.