# biblatex: citefield + url + href (TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].)

Tags: biblatex, urls

- Is there a "off-the-shelf" way to use the url of a bibliography entry in the `\href{}`
  command using the `\citefield{}{}` command, for example `\href{\citefield{ctan}{url}}{link}`?
- The MWE below gives an error (`TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].`).
- I found an [8-year old related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191174) but I was hoping that now there is a easier way to do it.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[cite] \cite{ctan}
\item[citefield] \citefield{ctan}{url}
\item[href] \href{http://www.ctan.org}{link}
\item[href + citefield] %\href{\citefield{ctan}{url}}{link} % <-- Comment in/out to test.
\end{description}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Related

- [BibLaTeX' \citefield not expanded as expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191174)

Comment: `biblatex` has no user-facing commands to extract fields expandably. All commands you could use to obtain entry data just print that data and are not expandable. So the best solution depends on your use case. There is something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290611/35864 if the text you want to link is available in the `biblatex` entry itself (or can easily be generated there). And there are workarounds like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467262/35864 if you need to pass arbitrary text to the command.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. Could you provide an answer that allows me the same function as \href{\citefield{ctan}{url}}{link}? Meaning, that the URL is in the bib entry and that one only needs to have two arguments, bib key and link text?

Comment: If I understand correctly, that's pretty much what https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467262/35864 does.

Comment: @moewe Oh, sorry that I did not get that (shouldn't look at the code on my phone and instead use a proper screen)! I will try your linked answer, thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: @moewe Just FYI, I posted an "answer" that shows my actual use case. I use your code inside a `\item[]` as `\item[{\myCiteBibURL[link text]{bib key}}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach here depends on your use case.

If you want to link arbitrary text that is provided on the fly in-document to the URL of an entry, the solution from [create a hyperlink by using the url stored in the bibliography reference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467262/35864) is probably the way to go.

But if you actually want to link content that is part of the `.bib` entry or that can be generated programmatically by `biblatex`, then you should use the approach from [What is the simplest way to extract a URL from a .bib entry for use in \href{}{} (probably using Biblatex)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290611/35864).

---

In your answer you always only link the `shorttitle`. In that case you could go for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  hidelinks,
  colorlinks = true,
  linkcolor = blue,
  urlcolor = blue,
  citecolor = red,
]{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urllink}{\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\titleurlcite}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[urllink]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{ISO_TS_16951_2021,
  type        = {Technical Specification (ISO/TS)},
  title       = {Road vehicles
                 -- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems (TICS)
                 -- Procedures for determining priority of on-board messages presented to drivers},
  shorttitle  = {ISO/TS 16951:20216},
  url         = {https://www.iso.org/standard/81103.html},
  number      = {ISO/TS 16951:2021},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author      = {ISO},
  date        = {2021-03},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\titleurlcite{ISO_TS_16951_2021}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Linked shorttitle]

---

If you only need this for the `description` environment, you can make `biblatex` generate that with a `\printbibliography`. (Again, how exactly this should be implemented depends very much on your precise use case. This is just a straightforward way of implementing it. You may or may not need some tweaks to have this behave as you want.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  hidelinks,
  colorlinks = true,
  linkcolor = blue,
  urlcolor = blue,
  citecolor = red,
]{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urllink}{\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}

\newrobustcmd*{\localbibliographyalias}[2]{%
  \csedef{blx@bbx@#1}{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname blx@bbx@#2\endcsname}}

\defbibenvironment{standardslist}
  {\localbibliographyalias{report}{standardslist}%
   \list
     {\printfield[urllink]{shorttitle}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\defbibcheck{standardslist}{%
  \ifentrytype{report}
    {}
    {\skipentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{standardslist}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printtext{The title of this document is}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{ISO_TS_16951_2021,
  type = {Technical Specification (ISO/TS)},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems (TICS) -- Procedures for determining priority of on-board messages presented to drivers},
  shorttitle = {ISO/TS 16951:20216},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/81103.html},
  number = {ISO/TS 16951:2021},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2021-03},
}
@techreport{ISO_15006_2011,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems -- Specifications for in-vehicle auditory presentation},
  shorttitle = {ISO 15006:2011},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/55322.html},
  number = {ISO 15006:2011},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2011-10},
}
@techreport{ISO_TR_12204_2012,
  type = {Technical Report (ISO/TR)},
  title = {Road vehicles — Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems — Introduction to integrating safety critical and time critical warning signals},
  shorttitle = {ISO/TR 12204:2012},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/55322.html},
  number = {ISO/TR 12204:2012},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2012-11},
}
@techreport{ISO_TR_16352_2005,
  type = {Technical Report (ISO/TR)},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of in-vehicle presentation for transport information and control systems -- Warning systems},
  shorttitle = {ISO/TR 16352:2005},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/37859.html},
  number = {ISO/TR 16352:2005},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2005-12},
}
@techreport{ISO_15005_2017,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of transportation and control systems -- Dialogue management principles and compliance procedures},
  shorttitle = {ISO 15005:2017},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/69238.html},
  number = {ISO 15005:2017},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2017-02},
}
@techreport{ISO_15007_2020,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles -— Measurement and analysis of driver visual behaviour with respect to transport information and control systems},
  shorttitle = {ISO 15007:2020},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/63220.html},
  number = {ISO 15007:2020},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2011-10},
}
@techreport{ISO_15008_2017,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems -- Specifications and test procedures for in-vehicle visual presentation},
  shorttitle = {ISO 15005:2017},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/62784.html},
  number = {ISO 15008:2017},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2017-09},
}
@techreport{ISO_16673_2017,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems -- Occlusion method to assess visual demand due to the use of in-vehicle systems},
  shorttitle = {ISO 16673:2017},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/71508.html},
  number = {ISO 16673:2017},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2005-12},
}
@techreport{ISO_17287_2003,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles —- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems —- Procedure for assessing suitability for use while driving},
  shorttitle = {ISO 17287:2003},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/30597.html},
  number = {ISO 17287:2003},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2003-04},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{ISO_15006_2011,ISO_TR_16352_2005,ISO_TS_16951_2021,ISO_15005_2017,
  ISO_15006_2011,ISO_15007_2020,ISO_15008_2017,ISO_16673_2017,
  ISO_17287_2003,ISO_TR_12204_2012}

Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,aksin,moraux}

\printbibliography[env=standardslist, check=standardslist, title=Lots of standards]
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Standards biblist]

Comment: Very elegant, thank you.

Comment: In your `\titleurlcite` command, where does it say to use the `shorttitle` field? I just see `indextitle` and `labeltitle`. I assume the "secret sauce" is somewhere in `{\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[urllink]{labeltitle}}`.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner `labeltitle` is created by Biber according to `\DeclareLabeltitle`. By default it is the first of `shorttitle`-`title`-`maintitle` that is nonempty. In our case we always get `shorttitle`, but the macro will also work in other cases, when there is only a `title` and no `shorttitle`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Happy Xmas!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you. Merry Christmas to you, too!

Answer (score 0):

Based on user's moewe great comment and already existing answer, this is how I now use his code. Maybe this is useful for future reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes} % for \enquote
\usepackage[
    hidelinks,
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue,
    urlcolor = blue,
    citecolor = red,
    ]{hyperref}

% Based on % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467262/
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myCiteBibURL}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\iffieldundef{url}
     {\PackageWarning{biblatex}
        {The entry \thefield{entrykey} has no URL.\MessageBreak
         No link will be created}%
      \printfield{postnote}}
     {\href{\thefield{url}}
        {\iffieldundef{postnote}
           {\PackageWarning{biblatex}
              {Text argument missing,\MessageBreak
               using the title for entry\MessageBreak
               \thefield{entrykey}}%
            \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
           {\printfield{postnote}}}}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{ISO_TS_16951_2021,
  type = {Technical Specification (ISO/TS)},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems (TICS) -- Procedures for determining priority of on-board messages presented to drivers},
  shorttitle = {ISO/TS 16951:20216},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/81103.html},
  number = {ISO/TS 16951:2021},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2021-03},
}

@techreport{ISO_15006_2011,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems -- Specifications for in-vehicle auditory presentation},
  shorttitle = {ISO 15006:2011},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/55322.html},
  number = {ISO 15006:2011},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2011-10},
}

@techreport{ISO_TR_12204_2012,
  type = {Technical Report (ISO/TR)},
  title = {Road vehicles — Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems — Introduction to integrating safety critical and time critical warning signals},
  shorttitle = {ISO/TR 12204:2012},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/55322.html},
  number = {ISO/TR 12204:2012},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2012-11},
}

@techreport{ISO_TR_16352_2005,
  type = {Technical Report (ISO/TR)},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of in-vehicle presentation for transport information and control systems -- Warning systems},
  shorttitle = {ISO/TR 16352:2005},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/37859.html},
  number = {ISO/TR 16352:2005},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2005-12},
}

@techreport{ISO_15005_2017,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of transportation and control systems -- Dialogue management principles and compliance procedures},
  shorttitle = {ISO 15005:2017},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/69238.html},
  number = {ISO 15005:2017},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2017-02},
}

@techreport{ISO_15007_2020,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles -— Measurement and analysis of driver visual behaviour with respect to transport information and control systems},
  shorttitle = {ISO 15007:2020},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/63220.html},
  number = {ISO 15007:2020},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2011-10},
}

@techreport{ISO_15008_2017,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems -- Specifications and test procedures for in-vehicle visual presentation},
  shorttitle = {ISO 15005:2017},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/62784.html},
  number = {ISO 15008:2017},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2017-09},
}

@techreport{ISO_16673_2017,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles -- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems -- Occlusion method to assess visual demand due to the use of in-vehicle systems},
  shorttitle = {ISO 16673:2017},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/71508.html},
  number = {ISO 16673:2017},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2005-12},
}

@techreport{ISO_17287_2003,
  type = {Standard},
  title = {Road vehicles —- Ergonomic aspects of transport information and control systems —- Procedure for assessing suitability for use while driving},
  shorttitle = {ISO 17287:2003},
  url = {https://www.iso.org/standard/30597.html},
  number = {ISO 17287:2003},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization (ISO)},
  author = {{ISO}},
  date = {2003-04},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
% \item[{\myCiteBibURL[]{}}] Text % <-- The additional "{}" inside the optional argumeny of the \item command is needed because of the "[]" of the \myCiteBibURL command.
\item[{\myCiteBibURL[\citefield{ISO_15006_2011}{shorttitle}]{ISO_15006_2011}}] The title of the document is \enquote{\citefield{ISO_15006_2011}{title}} \parencite{ISO_15006_2011}.
\item[{\myCiteBibURL[\citefield{ISO_TR_16352_2005}{shorttitle}]{ISO_TR_16352_2005}}] The title of the document is \enquote{\citefield{ISO_TR_16352_2005}{title}} \parencite{ISO_TR_16352_2005}. 
\item[{\myCiteBibURL[\citefield{ISO_TS_16951_2021}{shorttitle}]{ISO_TS_16951_2021}}] The title of the document is \enquote{\citefield{ISO_TS_16951_2021}{title}} \parencite{ISO_TS_16951_2021}.
\item[{\myCiteBibURL[\citefield{ISO_15005_2017}{shorttitle}]{ISO_15005_2017}}] The title of the document is \enquote{\citefield{ISO_15005_2017}{title}} \parencite{ISO_15005_2017}.
\item[{\myCiteBibURL[\citefield{ISO_15006_2011}{shorttitle}]{ISO_15006_2011}}] The title of the document is \enquote{\citefield{ISO_15006_2011}{title}} \parencite{ISO_15006_2011}.
\item[{\myCiteBibURL[\citefield{ISO_15007_2020}{shorttitle}]{ISO_15007_2020}}] The title of the document is \enquote{\citefield{ISO_15007_2020}{title}} \parencite{ISO_15007_2020}.
\item[{\myCiteBibURL[\citefield{ISO_15008_2017}{shorttitle}]{ISO_15008_2017}}] The title of the document is \enquote{\citefield{ISO_15008_2017}{title}} \parencite{ISO_15008_2017}.
\item[{\myCiteBibURL[\citefield{ISO_16673_2017}{shorttitle}]{ISO_16673_2017}}] The title of the document is \enquote{\citefield{ISO_16673_2017}{title}} \parencite{ISO_16673_2017}.
\item[{\myCiteBibURL[\citefield{ISO_17287_2003}{shorttitle}]{ISO_17287_2003}}] The title of the document is \enquote{\citefield{ISO_17287_2003}{title}} \parencite{ISO_17287_2003}.
\item[{\myCiteBibURL[\citefield{ISO_TR_12204_2012}{shorttitle}]{ISO_TR_12204_2012}}] The title of the document is \enquote{\citefield{ISO_TR_12204_2012}{title}} \parencite{ISO_TR_12204_2012}.
\end{description}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you always want to show the `shorttitle` and link that to the URL, the approach from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290681/35864 is more elegant. If your use case is always this formulaic, an even more elegant solution would be to pack all of this up into a `biblatex` macro directly.

Comment: @moewe If you have time and motivation, then please provide an answer for a biblatex macro solution and I will accept it.