Link produced by href taking a command as first argument is not working "as I want"
I am trying to define a command that takes a bib key, gets its title, author, and DOI, and makes a hyperlink in which the link is the DOI address and the text shown is the paper title. I need this to be done in the text, not (or not only) in the list of references. However, I cannot make that the first argument of href to be evaluated, so the produced link is not what I want. (The second argument of href is working as I expect.) I am not an expert in latex by any means, but I suspect that this has something to do with first argument needing to be a text string, and/or with the \citefield{#1}{doi} command not being "evaluated" or "expanded". Is there any way that this can be done?
Here is a (not so minimal) MWE, followed by the output I get with the link problem:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Weinberg:1965zz,
    author = "Weinberg, Steven",
    title = "{Evidence That the Deuteron Is Not an Elementary Particle}",
    doi = "10.1103/PhysRev.137.B672",
    journal = "Phys. Rev.",
    volume = "137",
    pages = "B672--B678",
    year = "1965"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue},
    citecolor={blue},
    urlcolor={blue}
}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}


%\newcommand{\FancyCite}[1]{%
%\citeauthor{#1}, \href{https://doi.org/\citefield{#1}{doi}}{\citefield{#1}{title}}
%}

\newcommand{\FancyCite}[1]{%
\edef\AuxString{https://doi.org/\citefield{#1}{doi}}
\citeauthor{#1}, \href{\AuxString}{\citefield{#1}{title}}
}

\begin{document}

Here some reference: \cite{Weinberg:1965zz}. 

Check that the DOI reference is properly caught: \citefield{Weinberg:1965zz}{doi}.

However, the following link is not what I expect: 

\FancyCite{Weinberg:1965zz}

\vspace{1cm}


I would like the link to direct me to \texttt{https://doi.org/\citefield{Weinberg:1965zz}{doi}}

\printbibliography

\end{document}



you should define a proper citation command, see the biblatex documentation. Inside such a command you can access the fields.

Thank you. I don't know much about DeclareCiteCommand, but I was able to introduce the proper DOI in href first argument by using \thefield{doi} in DeclareCiteCommand. However, I was not able to reproduce the format I was looking for.
But then the answer below came, which is exactly what I want.

Taking code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191197/4427
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Weinberg:1965zz,
    author = "Weinberg, Steven",
    title = "{Evidence That the Deuteron Is Not an Elementary Particle}",
    doi = "10.1103/PhysRev.137.B672",
    journal = "Phys. Rev.",
    volume = "137",
    pages = "B672--B678",
    year = "1965"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue},
    citecolor={blue},
    urlcolor={blue}
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\@savedoi}{}{\savefield{doi}{\@saveddoi}}{}{}
\newcommand{\hrefdoi}[2]{%
  \@savedoi{#1}%
  \href{https://doi.org/\@saveddoi}{#2}%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\FancyCite}[1]{%
  \citeauthor{#1}, %
  \hrefdoi{#1}{\citefield{#1}{title}}%
}

\begin{document}

Here some reference: \cite{Weinberg:1965zz}. 

Check that the DOI reference is properly caught: \citefield{Weinberg:1965zz}{doi}.

However, the following link is not what I expect: 

\FancyCite{Weinberg:1965zz}

\vspace{1cm}


I would like the link to direct me to \texttt{https://doi.org/\citefield{Weinberg:1965zz}{doi}}

\printbibliography

\end{document}



Perfect, beautiful. It works like charm. I will try to learn the details of the \hrefdoi command. Thanks!
